# How to test for differences in gradient between time-series

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have time-series data where I've generated measurements of the same variable using different techniques, for a group of samples.

An example of my data looks like this:

```
Sample    Technique    Time_point    Variable
     1            A             0        14.5
     2            A             0        13.5
     1            A             1        14.7
     2            A             1        15.4
```

I have six different samples - these were divided into four and subjected to four different techniques. I have measurements from around 50 time points.

I want to test which technique is most reliable - i.e. for which technique do my measurements for my Variable remain closest to those taken at Time_point zero.

I started by subtracting the measurements at time-point zero from each subsequent time-point - my thinking was that this would mean variation between samples would be accounted for.  To demonstrate what I mean, the four values in the example table above would now be: 0, 0, 0.2, 1.9

I then used linear model (Variable ~ Time) to look at how the measurements change over time.  Doing this I can see that the regression coefficient differs between the treatment, and which treatment looks best.  However, I can't think how to test for a statistical difference between the treatments.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's a dput of a slice of the actual data - everything for Time_point 1. As I said, there are about 50 Time_points, including zero.

```
structure(list(Sample = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
Technique = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Time_point = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Variable = c(0.310926466, 
0.92436022, 0.859052911, 0.461566996, 0.573988696, 0.322502093, 
0.547209977, 0.056521271, 0.917202812, 0.547052115, 0.966242263, 
0.201885797, 0.105904834, 0.032739442, 0.267122038, 0.077291406, 
0.1663824, 0.76340688, 0.643163407, 0.368830206, 0.009501023, 
0.628387174, 0.108224747, 0.178916308)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-24L), .Names = c("Sample", "Technique", "Time_point", "Variable"
))
```

Comment: Can you post your whole data using `dput()`? Also, your current method estimates the slope, but if there is no slope over time then this is not very informative. It may be more informative to test the mean, or SD?

Comment: @user2974951 The dput output is too long to post here - there are 50 time points for each sample/Technique.  I tried to describe the data and give an example - I'm happy to clarify if it's not clear?

Comment: Can you post a small complete subset of your data then? As I said, I would either test the mean or the SD of the differences.

Comment: @user2974951 I added a dput of a subset - everything for time-point 1

Comment: So you have one measurement at time 0 which you take to be the truth / reference. And I am assuming that you claim this value should not change over time? Then you use a different method to obtain 49 more values for 49 different time points? Now you want to test which technique remained closest to the truth? By time point? Or in total?

Comment: Not quite - for each Technique there are measurements at time 0, which are taken to be the truth/reference, and should not change over time.  The subsequent 49 values use the same Technique. I want to know which Technique remained closest to the truth for the longest time. i.e. it would be good to be able to say Technique A was reliable for 10 time points, but Technique B was reliable for 16 time points.

Comment: This is tough. If you really wanted to compare all 50 time points then you would have to transform these into factors and do all comparisons. Which may not be the best option anyway, since you could jump away from time point 0 at a given time point x, only to return back at time point x+1. You could try comparing the variance for each technique, such as through ANOVA, or something like segmented regression, to find whether there are breaks in your data through time, and compare the slopes for the first segments.